# Android: Detect when a Horizontal Scroll View has stopped scolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to do some events after a HorizontalScrollView finishes scrolling.

From my research I have determined that I need to subclass HorizontalScollView, but what to methods should I override?

How can I detect it has finished scrolling?

Comment: The answer of this topic: [8181828](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling) with the runnable works quite well. Only `getScrollY()` has to be replaced by `getScrollX()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I previously supplied has a better solution:

Check it out here -> [Android: Detect when ScrollView stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)

I hope this helps get you started.

Comment: I am extending HorizontalScrollView. But, I cant find this isFinished() method. what is mScroller? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This does not work.  mScroller is a private variable in ScrollView.  The linked question does have a solution though.

Comment: mScroller and isFinished() are private and will not be available in extended class.