# How can I detect that the HorizontalScrollView has reached an end in Android?

Tags: java, android

.If the HorizontalScrollView  reaches the dead end "the right" aroow will disable and if it  reaches the first position " the left " arrow will disable.I searched a lot but no use.Sorry for my poor english.Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Detect when ScrollView stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

Check answer: [Android: Detect when ScrollView stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling/10198865#10198865)

You have to replace getScrollY() with getScrollX() and it should work.