# Capture onScroll event in Android ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, onscrolllistener

Simple scenario - ScrollView hosting a single LinearLayout which has several children - the preferred pattern to allow a scroll enabled views in developing on Android.

I need to capture onScrollEvents, start, stop, etc. that are readily available and work very well if I use ListView/onScrollListener combination.

A dedicated widget for scrolling a view DOES NOT have the built-in capabilities to capture these events? Come On! I have tried OnTouchEvent listener, onGestureListener, etc - all work arounds and all meant for something else. What am I missing here?

Comment: The exact same thing has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling
Basically, it's not available out of the box.

Comment: Exactly - we should probably ask another thousand times so someone on Android dev team will hear it or at least provide a reasonable excuse. - will have to pick one of the hundreds of work-arounds, probably extending ScrollView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have onScrollListener for a ScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview)

Comment: Salam.

This answer worked for me very good:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365539/1676736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no pre-built way for getting these events. However, there are two workarounds:

- Use a `ListView` instead
- Build your own custom ScrollView with ScrollListener. This is not that hard to achieve and [has been done before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952629/1691231).