# How to scroll to a location in a scrollView without animating?

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-scrollview

I've been doing some research and haven't found a functional solution.

In short, I need to programmatically `scrollTo` a position in a scrollView (horizontal if anyone wants to know), **without** animating/seeing the animation. `scrollTo` performs the animation.  Everything I have tried thus far is visibly scrolling the scrollView.  I want to be able to instantly set a location for it to jump to.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I achieved an "instant scroll" by using `scrollView.scrollTo(x,y)`

However, it did not work alone.  To get it working without seeing a scroll animation, I had to perform my logic only when I knew the scrollView stopped.  I implemented what tulio84z suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10198865/3512120)

By knowing when my scrollView finished scrolling, I was able to then use `scrollTo` without seeing any scrolling animations.

Answer (score 1):

These are the diffrent methods to set scroll posiotion/location

```
ScrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y);
ScrollView.smoothScrollTo(int x, int y);
ScrollView.smoothScrollBy(int x, int y);
```

Try one of them. Hope It will help you.

Comment: Thanks Ankit Kumar.  I was aware of the smoothScrolls but they were obviously not what I was looking for.  I got it working using the scrollTo method and some additional help.  See my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollBy (int x, int y)` if you want to scroll immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended playing with both scrollBy and scrollTo and got it working using scrollTo.