# Detect scroll view reaching its top - Android

Tags: android, scroll

I have used **scrollview** in my Android app using **activity_main.xml**. The scroll is working perfectly.
But the thing is i need to add a **Scroll to top button** so that if the user starts scrolling the button should be visible like the link below..

http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/scroll-to-top/scrolltotop.html?

I need to do this in Android..

Comment: Are you using the listview or gridview in yours scrollView??

Comment: No i m not using any views here..

Comment: try scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(0,0); in button click

Comment: thank you @kgandroid.. but i need to view the button only when the page scrolls..

Comment: You can use something like this, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview/23365539#23365539.

Comment: You have to play with Visibility and Invisibility of button when the user scroll down the view...On click on that button use these View.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 


Here View is the top View of the scrollView

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling

Comment: ya i m doing the same.. My confusion is how to detect when the user reaches top of the screen so that i can make it invisible..

Answer (score 11):

Use the below code to detect the top of the scroll.

```
final ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener onScrollChangedListener = new
            ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    if (scrollview.getScrollY() == 0) {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                    } else
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }
            };
    scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private ViewTreeObserver observer;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (observer == null) {
                observer = scrollview.getViewTreeObserver();
                observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
            } else if (!observer.isAlive()) {
                observer.removeOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
                observer = scrollview.getViewTreeObserver();
                observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: May I ask? When will the observer is not alive?

Comment: I think you should return true in onTouch method. by the way thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
 scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                if (scrollView != null) {
                    if (scrollView.getScrollY()==0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"top",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Kotlin this way

```
scrollView.scrollY == 0
```