# How to check in ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() wether scroll finished, is IDLE?

Tags: java, android, horizontal-scrolling

I need to know when user initiated scroll has finished, but have no clue, how to access this info. `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener()` has only one abstract method `onScrollChanged`, but has no `public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)` sort of abstract method with `state` argument.

```
horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This class is written for you I must say. :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/38684097/6547129

Comment: I think there is no way you can do it with `ViewTreeObserver`. See this question for solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling