# How to detect whether Android Scroll view is in idle state?

Tags: android, android-button, android-scrollview

I was trying to hide a button during scroll view is in idle state.the button should be invisible only during scrolling time.(Rest of the time button should be visible)

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new ScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        if (scrollX == scrollY)  {
            Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if ((scrollY > oldScrollY)) {
            Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Detect when ScrollView stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)

Comment: This will help you for sure: [Android Detect Scrolling issue](https://edu.masoomyf.com/2022/09/blog-post.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the solution

```
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event ) {
            switch ( event.getAction( ) ) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.e( "SCROLL", "ACTION_SCROLL" );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.e( "SCROLL", "ACTION_DOWN" );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.e( "SCROLL", "SCROLL_STOP" );
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: While user touch up, it show immediately SCROLL_STOP, but scrollview is still scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is a little old and `ScrollView` are not as used, I had to implement something related to this, I'm using a `NestedScrollView` per recommendation and Kotlin.

If you are using Java this won't be possible or as 'clean', you would need to create static util methods instead, with Kotlin you can do extension functions as shown.
If you are using a `ScrollView` just change what you see here from `NestedScrollView` to `ScrollView`.

#### I'll show two ways to implement this:

First, create your `NestedScrollViewExtensions.kt` file:

## 1.

If you want a simplified (my preferred) version just add this snippet to your `NestedScrollViewExtensions.kt` file:

```
fun NestedScrollView.onScrollStateChanged(startDelay: Long = 100, stopDelay: Long = 400, listener: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                handler.postDelayed({
                    listener.invoke(true)
                }, startDelay)
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                handler.postDelayed({
                    listener.invoke(false)
                }, stopDelay)
            }
        }
        false // Do not consume events
    }
}
```

This way the implementation is cleaner:

```
        scroll_view.onScrollStateChanged { isScrolling -> 
            if(isScrolling) fab.shrink() else fab.extend()
        }
```

## 2

And the not so clean way

```
interface NestedViewScrollChangedListener {
    fun onScrollStart()

    fun onScrollStop()
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
fun NestedScrollView.onScrollStateChanged(listener: NestedViewScrollChangedListener) {
    this.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when(event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                handler.postDelayed({
                    listener.onScrollStart()
                }, 100)
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                handler.postDelayed({
                    listener.onScrollStop()
                }, 400)
            }
        }
        false // Don't consume touch events
    }
}
```

In here I'm using a simple delay that works for me as I need to have an animation happen, feel free to remove all the `handler.postDelay()` and call the listener directly.

The interface above `NestedViewScrollChangedListener` needs to be implemented like this:

```
scroll_view.onScrollStateChanged(object : NestedViewScrollChangedListener {
            override fun onScrollStart() {
                fab.shrink()
            }

            override fun onScrollStop() {
                fab.extend()
            }
        })
```

Good luck :)

Comment: add view.performClick() above false to solve warning of "onTouch lambda should call View#performClick when a click is detected"

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin you can use this

```
inline fun NestedScrollView.scrollState(crossinline idle: () -> Unit, crossinline scrolled: () -> Unit) {
    setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                scrolled()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                idle()
            }
        }
        false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
            //do your stuff here
        }
}
```

Comment: i am not using listivew. i used only scrollview