# Xamarin Forms - attaching scrollview.Scrolled to a function

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, scrollview

When I attach a scrollview to a function like this

```
textScroll.Scrolled += (sender, e) => { onScrolled(); };
```

Each time I scroll up or down, OnScrolled() is called multiple times.  I know I can get the size of the content and compare it to the ScrollY value, obviously the ScrollY value changes each time, but as far as I can see I won't know when the last call happens (per user scroll).

I only want to call this once per scroll, failing that call it each time as is happening now, but only act when I know I'm on the last call.

Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but with a custom renderer for each platform.

On **iOS:** you will want to implement delegates for `DecelerationEnded` and `WillEndDragging`. The reason for also implementing DecelerationEnded is to allow for a *fling* by the user and waiting for the velocity to come to 0.

On **Android** it is a bit more complicated. Here is a native Android SO post I followed and translated into c# in a renderer. Works pretty well for me.
[Android: Detect when ScrollView stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)

After having both implemented, you can call to your **Xamarin.Forms** view in order to notify that the view has **Stopped** scrolling (i.e. final call)