# Implement toolbar like Gmail app with smart shadow and translucent statusbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gmail, android-toolbar, shadow

How to implement a toolbar like the new Gmail app that is translucent and have the same color as status bar and also get a shadow only on scroll.

I have uploaded the screen capture here: [gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AR7m.jpg)

this is the code of my main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ima_default_background"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<!--the frame I load my fragments in-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<!--toolbar frame-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <net.karthikraj.shapesimage.ShapesImage
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@color/tool_bar_color"
        app:shapeDrawable="@drawable/one_rounded_rectangle_white_24dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText" />
</FrameLayout>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    style="@style/navigation_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigation.ActiveItemTextAppearance"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I achieved the transparency effect for toolbar using this tutorial [Draw under Status Bar like a Pro](https://proandroiddev.com/draw-under-status-bar-like-a-pro-db38cfff2870?source=bookmarks---------2-----------------------)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any kind of native implementation already available for this. One way I could think of doing it is to add another view below your toolbar with a grey background that is around 1dp in height, then implement this scrolling listener https://stackoverflow.com/a/10198865/9416912.

Give the view an id, when it user starts scrolling, you made it visible with a fade in animation. Then when user stops, you make the view invisible and fade out the view.

Comment: There is an `app:elevation` attribute that takes care of the AppbarLayout shadow. Thanks for the answer. 